# Update element of immutable vector - vector-set

Tags: racket

I'm using vectors to build a table for implement a dynamic program, it involves updating each element of the vector sequentially. But why is there no `vector-set` for immutable vectors? There is only `vector-set!` for mutable vectors, but we can see that there is `dict-set` and `dict-set!` for immutable and mutable dictionaries, also there is `hash-set` and `hash-set!` for immutable and mutable hash tables.

Comment: You're right, there is no built in functional `vector-set` operation. However there are libraries that provide persistent vectors that directly support this. For example the [pvector](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pvector/index.html) library supports the [set-nth](http://docs.racket-lang.org/collections/collections-api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._data%2Fcollection..rkt%29._set-nth%29%29) and [update-nth](http://docs.racket-lang.org/collections/collections-api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._data%2Fcollection..rkt%29._update-nth%29%29) operations for functional update.

Comment: @AlexKnauth Yes thanks for pvector, but I wonder why? The reason could not have `vector-set`.

Comment: The `pvector` library doesn't have to copy the whole vector to functionally update it, because of how it's structured. But the built-in vectors don't have that structure, so a functional `vector-set` on a built-in vector *would* have to copy the whole thing. That might be part of why it's left out, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `vector-set` is missing, is to prevent people inadvertently using it without realizing the operation is `O(n)` and not `O(1)`. Since `vector-set!` is `O(1)` it is not unlikely for someone to make this mistake.

Furthermore it is simple to write a `vector-set` when it is really needed:

```
#lang racket

(define (vector-set v i o)
  (vector->immutable-vector
   (for/vector ([j (in-range (vector-length v))])
     (if (= i j)
         o
         (vector-ref v j)))))

(vector-set (vector-immutable 10 11 12 13) 2 'a)
```

Output:

```
'#(10 11 a 13)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Racket 8.12 added [`vector-set/copy`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-set%2Fcopy%29%29) that returns a new copy of a vector with one element changed:

```lisp
Welcome to Racket v8.12 [cs].
> (vector-set/copy '#(1 2 3 4) 1 'foo)
'#(1 foo 3 4)
```

though I agree with the earlier comments that if you want to do this on a regular basis you should be looking into more appropriate data structures.